# SwiftUI ShareLink run code before sharesheet is shown

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `ShareLink` to share an image

```
ShareLink(item: image) {
    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
}
```

Now before I can share this image, I have to generate it with some function

```swift
@State var image: UIImage
var getImage() {
    // some code that updates @State variable
}
```

My `ShareLink` itself is in a context menu. My problem is that it is too expensive to generate this image (call the `getImage()` function) every time the view refreshes or the context menu is opened. Is there any way I can run code if the user taps on this ShareLink, that is then run and the results are then shown in the Share sheet?

Note: I know this is possible using UIKit as fallback to generate the sharesheet, using a function like this:

```swift
func actionSheet() {
        guard let urlShare = URL(string: "https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/") else { return }
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [urlShare], applicationActivities: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

as demonstrated in this article: https://medium.com/swift-productions/sharesheet-uiactivityviewcontroller-swiftui-47abcd69aba6

I am instead wondering if there is a way to do this with the new ios16 `ShareLink`

---

**Edit** I havent managed to get it to work with Sharelink yet. Here is the workaround that I am using:

```swift
Button {
                shareCollage()
            } label: {
                Label("Share Collage", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
            }
```

which calls

```swift
func shareCollage() {
        Task {
            if let screenshot = await takeScreenshot() {
                let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [screenshot], applicationActivities: nil)
                
                if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                    // otherwise iPad crashes
                    let thisViewVC = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
                    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = thisViewVC.view
                }
                
                UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.flatMap {($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? []}.first {$0.isKeyWindow}?.rootViewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Source: https://github.com/charelF/StickerPaste/blob/main/StickerPaste/ContentView.swift

Comment: Why not using a optional that you can initialise in onAppear, then the ShareLink could only be enable if image is not nil.

Comment: I generate the image once the user requests it, so this is not a viable solution as in that case, the user has to open the context menu, then click to generate the image (the image generation requires that the context menu is closed again), then they need to reopen the context menu, and only then would they see the additional button to save the image.. Thats a very cumbersome navigation.

Comment: save the image in a lazy var in your view model so it will only be generated once and is ready without delay once the use navigates your context menu. while the image is still nil, disable the menu with a view modifier

Comment: That is an interesting approach, but I dont think it will work. Problem is that the menu also contains other functionality. The menu needs to be available. I can not hide the 'share image' button in the menu before the image is generated as otherwhise there is no way to actually generate the image unless you do a complicated 2-step setup. Finally, a lazy var is also problematic as this image may also be re-generated and then shared again.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
let img = ImageModel(getImage: getImage)
ShareLink(item: img, preview: SharePreview(
    "shareImage",
    image: img
)) {
    Label("shareImage", systemImage: "photo")
}
```

and

```
struct ImageModel: Transferable {
    let getImage: () async -> UIImage?

    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        DataRepresentation(exportedContentType: .jpeg) { item in
            try await { () -> Data in
                if let img = await item.getImage(), let jpeg = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6) {
                    return jpeg
                } else {
                    throw ExportImageError.noImageFound
                }
            }()
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
enum ExportImageError: Error {
    case noImageFound
}
```

---

The only issue I'm having here is that `getImage()` is called twice, once for the preview and once for the export itself. You could just not use the preview, like so:

```
ShareLink(item: ImageModel(getImage: shareImage), preview: SharePreview(
    "shareImage",
    image: Image("photo")
)) {
    Label("shareImage", systemImage: "text.below.photo.fill")
}
```

or cache the result somehow. Maybe there's also a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I used `@State var imageForShare: ImageFile? = nil` for the image I wanted to share.

I don't think you need to generate the image every time the view refreshes. Just only generate the image (in `async` way) whenever the content of the image changes, and that way SwiftUI knows when it needs to update the image.

Since the async generating working in the background, it should not affect your view rendering.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work in my case. My image is basically a screencapture of the view, so every time the view changes (it contains draggable/movable elements which the user can move), i need to update the image. However there is some UI overlayed on top of my view, which I need to briefly remove before saving the view. So the flow is: modify view -> hide UI elemnt -> save view as img -> show UI element -> open sharelink. I can not redrwa the image all the time otherwhise the UI elements would just flicker around. Thanks for the idea though.